# ValueError: Failed to commit transaction in 5 attempts

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

**TL;DR** Transactions not updating the counters as expected

Scenerio:

I have sub collections called `projects` and `activities`.
projects collection is used to store information on any on going projects and activities collection serves as an audit trail to any change that occurs in projects collection.

I have written a cloud function which is triggered to activities collection `on create event`. Upon creation of a document in activities collection, I need to update a counter called `activityCount` in a document identified by `projectId` in projects sub collection.

The cloud function (some parts deleted due to brevity) is as follows:

```
@firestore.transactional
def update_activity_count_in_transaction(transaction, activity):
    """
    updates the activity count for a project
    """
    try:
        # get the project details of associated project at home/{orgId}/projects/{projectId}
        project = activity.project.doc_ref.get(transaction=transaction)

        # get the activity count from the transactional snapshot
        activity_count = project.get(FireBaseConfig.ACTIVITY_COUNT)

        # increment the counter using transaction
        transaction.update(activity.project.doc_ref, {FireBaseConfig.ACTIVITY_COUNT: activity_count + 1})
    except KeyError as err:
        print(err)

        # create activityCount key if not present in projects collection and increment the counter using transaction
        transaction.update(activity.project.doc_ref, {FireBaseConfig.ACTIVITY_COUNT: 1})
    print('transaction success')

    return True


def activity_on_create(event, context):
    """
    update the activity count in projects sub collection
    This is invoked on create event at home/{orgId}/activities/{activityId}
    """

    # parse the event data received from cloud functions into a FireStoreActivity object
    activity = FireStoreActivity(event, context)
    try:
        if not activity.project.id:
            print('no project id')
            return True

        # get firestore transaction object
        # activity.transaction() is equivalent to firestore.client().transaction()
        transaction = activity.transaction()

        # update the counter using transaction
        update_activity_count_in_transaction(transaction, activity)
    except Exception as err:
        pass
    return True
```

The following is the error upon doing so:

```
ValueError: Failed to commit transaction in 5 attempts
```

Traceback:

```
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 333, in run_background_function
    _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 199, in invoke_user_function
    return call_user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 196, in call_user_function
    event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context))
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 149, in activity_on_create
    raise err
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 146, in activity_on_create
    update_activity_count_in_transaction(transaction, activity)
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/transaction.py", line 327, in __call__
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Failed to commit transaction in 5 attempts.
```

> Note: This error occurs randomly and not all the time. But it does occur.

Any idea on what could have gone wrong here?

Comment: My guess is that the same document is being updated by many concurrent transactions. As a result some transactions cannot get a successful commit on the document, event after 5 consecutive attempts.

Comment: But the whole purpose of having a transaction is to have consistent reads and write even on concurrent edits. It's mentioned in their docs that firestore reruns the entire transaction again for consistency in such cases.

Comment: Yes, but in the face of repeated failures to commit a consistent snapshot, the client has to give up at some point. In case of the Python client it's retrying up to [5 times](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/firestore/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/transaction.py#L28) by default. It seems you can control this parameter by passing `max_attempts` argument to `client.transaction()`.

Comment: Yup I have increased it to 10 attempts. Maybe distributed counters are to be used incase there is a lot of concurrent reads. Add the above as the answer so that I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a transaction fails to commit because there are lot of concurrent writes to the same target documents, the Firestore clients will retry the transaction up to `N` times before giving up. In case of the Python Firestore client, [`N = 5`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/firestore/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/transaction.py#L28) by default. You can control this parameter by passing a `max_attempts` argument to the `client.transaction()` method call.